# specify username and password for VPN connection

Tags: login, password, vpn

I have *open-connect VPN* and would like to always have a connection, even before I login with my own account.

I have Ubuntu 16.04.2, `network-manager-openconnect-gnome`.

If I run the command line `nmcli con up id <VPN connection name>` it will work, however it asks for *username* in a pop-up window, even it remember my *username* in visible text; then it asks for *password*, even it remembers it too (with the bullets), so I cannot use the `nmcli` directly to accomplish what I want.

Of course I still don't know how to make it totally headless (I mean run this before I login to Ubuntu), but that's next question after I can create something to connect the *openconnect VPN* without asking me the *username* and *password*.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, after try and error I don't find a direct solution, but there is a workaround to use expect to achieve this.

Basically I write an expect script to send the Username and Password to the nmcli. Specifically that is

1. `sudo apt-get install expect`, this will install the expect package
2. create a file, call it `connectvpn.sh`

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/expect -f

   spawn nmcli -a con up id <VPN ID>
   expect "Username:"
   send "<username>\r"
   expect "Password:"
   send "<password>\r"
   expect "$ "
   ```
3. `chmod a+x connectvpn.sh`
4. now run it and it will work

Of course disadvantage is the username ans password will be saved in plain text in the script, but this is the best solution I can find.